# Выделить границы на участке изображения

Tags: python

Нужно выделить на фото участок изображения, где есть коричневый материал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью skimage сделал следующее:

```
im = io.imread('sp.png')
grayscale = rgb2gray(im)
edges = feature.canny(grayscale,sigma=2)
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как теперь на оригинальное изображение нанести полученный контур?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]